# Manipulating with UIImage

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a problem with `UIImage`.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
   viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController labelContents]];
    if(currentIndex == self.modelArray.count-1)
    {
        return nil;
    }    ContentViewController *contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] init];
    contentViewController.labelContents = [self.modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex + 1];
    if(currentIndex > 0)
    {
        [[contentViewController firstimage] setImage :nil];
    } else if (currentIndex == 0) {
        contentViewController.firstimage_.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    }
    return contentViewController;
}
```

So the idea is: When the app starts, it will display an image. But when I go to a page that is not the first one, the image will not be displayed.

I have tried to set the image to `nil`, pass another image, and so many ways but I still have the same image on every page!

Please advise what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code could use more descriptive ivar names and inline comments, but one thing I noticed right away:  why do you set the image two different ways in there (one via a "`setImage:`" call and the other via a "`.image`" property)?  Also, if you set breakpoints on that code and step through it, does "`currentIndex`" ever become greater than zero?

Comment: @Michael:Yes, the currentIndex becomes more than zero, this code is from Demo - UIPageViewControllerDemo.Regarding the different ways : I have tried both ways, via setImage and .image, it just won't change. You can try the demo, it's like a book pages demo, it will show on every page it's number, but what i want is to add image on the top of  every page or remove image on some - DYNAMICALLY.

Comment: This is how the image is set on new ContentViewController: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myLabel.text = self.labelContents;
    self.firstimage.image = self.firstimage_.image;
} and in the code above i have tried to set nil on both: firstimage_ and firstimage